# Python: How do you make your code ask the same thing again if they answer with an integer out of range? My example below:

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I make this question asking for an input over and over until the user gets a valid answer between 5 and 25?

```
newGen = int(input("Input number of new generations to model (should be between 5 and 25\n)"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to catch the ValueError and loop it.

```
newGen = None
while newGen is None or (newGen < 5 or newGen > 25):
     try:
         newGen = int(input("Input number of new generations to model (should be between 5 and 25\n)"))
     except ValueError:
         pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newGen = 0
while newGen not in range(5, 26):
    newGen = int(input("Input number of new generations to model (should be between 5 and 25\n)"))
```